# Adobe scripting compatibility for different products

Tags: photoshop-scripting, illustrator-scripting

I am trying to understand scripting for adobe products using extendscript and I have a doubt whether I can re-use a script between different adobe products like ai, ps, pp and ae? Will there be some kind of granular level modifications between each of these product's apis?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a proper answer for this question. On the surface level, yea, you can write a script that works in all of those applications, but in the end it depends a lot on what the script does. Every application has their own specific properties and methods that the other apps don't have. You can do a conditional check which app the script is being run in and use different methods based on that, but like I said... it super depends on what the script does. You'll find out at some point if you start writing the script.

Comment: @Joonas At this moment, I am trying to create a panel in which the user can fill out certain details and select a file. Once he hits submit, I want to upload the file along with the details to my server using my API. Also, Is scripting for CS different from CC?

Comment: Scripted panels work really badly in illustrator, hardly worth doing at all. Not sure about socket programming.

Comment: I haven't done file uploads from a CEP extension myself and I don't know if there are any specific quirks there to watch out, but it sounds general enough that it could work. Scripting in general (Extendscript) is pretty much the same in CS and CC, but extensions may have a few hurdles. I don't really know though.

Answer (score 1):

They are like if they were separate programs from different companies (because that is what the separate divisions kindof are). They have some similarities but not that much (mainly because they use a similar unerlying module). AE is very different from PS and AI that are closer. But AI has the least mature scripting interface, PS has a tool to turn unscripted action to mystical calls. AE and InDesign have much more mature scripting interfaces. After effects is the most different one scripting wise.